Android ScrollView LinearLayout not scrolling
I have a scrollview, a linearlayout inside it, and other layout and textinputlayout components inside the linearlayout. But when I open the keyboard, my textinputedittexts at the bottom of keyboard cannot be scrolled. I tried the adjustResize and adjustPan keys in the manifest file, but they did not work either. My problem here is that ScrollView does not work at all.
CODE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
    tools:context=".presentation.view.RegisterFragment">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_bold"
                android:text="@string/registerMainText"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                android:text="@string/registerExpText"
                android:textColor="#676666"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Kullanıcı Adı"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                app:counterMaxLength="14"
                app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameEdtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_person"
                    android:maxLength="14"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="İsim"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                app:counterMaxLength="20"
                app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameEdtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_pen"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailEdtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Şifre"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                app:counterMaxLength="20"
                app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                app:endIconMinSize="60dp"
                app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                app:endIconTint="#494949"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordEdtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Telefon"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                app:counterMaxLength="15"
                app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main"
                app:prefixText="+90">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/phoneEdtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_phone"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/birthInputLayout"
                    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green_main"
                    app:cursorColor="@color/green_main"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/green_main">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/birthEdtTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:cursorVisible="false"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:hint="Doğum Tarihi"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroupRegister"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.widget.RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioBtnWomen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtn_selector"
                        android:text="Kadın" />

                    <android.widget.RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioBtnMen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtn_selector"
                        android:text="Erkek" />
                </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/onboarding_button_green"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="FITGATHER'A KATIL!"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
                    android:text="Zaten bir hesabın mı var?" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loginTxtBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_bold"
                    android:text="Giriş yap"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_main" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


Did I make a bug here that prevents scrolling?

I solved the problem by deleting window.setFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS),WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)) method from related fragment. It causes some layout problems.
